# Open Facebook Messenger from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, url, text, messenger

Does anyone know how can I open the Facebook messenger application with a pre-filled text?

For example, to open the messenger app at a specified user, you can write the following:

```
 NSURL *fbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb-messenger://user-thread/USER_ID"]; 
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: fbURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: fbURL];
}
```

For Whats app is very easy:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@", @"String to post here"]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me how have you achieved that. I am facing similar issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is such a function but it exists only in Facebook's SDK.

Look at this - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

Comment: Hello, can you please show me which one it is? I have looked for a couple of hours and didn't find anything related to messages.

Comment: @DenisaToderean check the link in the updated answer. It's the closest you can get to in the current version of FB's SDK for iOS.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share I think that this is it, the message dialog :)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4 & 5**

```
private func inviteViaFacebook() {
    let id = "akbarkhanshinwar"
    // If you have User id the use this URL
    let urlWithId = "fb-messenger://user-thread/\(id)"
    // If you don't have User id then use this URL
    let urlWithoutId = "fb-messenger://user-thread"
    if let url = URL(string: urlWithId) {

        // this will open your Messenger App
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
            (success) in

            if success == false {
                // If Messenger App is not installed then it will open browser.
                // If you have User id the use this URL
                let urlWithIdForBrowser = "https://m.me/\(id)"
                // If you don't have User id then use this URL
                let urlWithoutIdForBrowser = "https://m.me"
                let url = URL(string: urlWithIdForBrowser)
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome